# Fantasy manga where female MC is looking for savior and mistakes man for him

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, wizards

I’ve been looking all over but can’t find the name I’m looking for the name of a manga, it’s about a powerful female lead magician/wizard looking for her savior that saved her when she was young( she was being hunted because of hair I think). She mistakes someone for him and somehow goes on a adventure with him. Later in the story they become a couple and some how go back in time, the ml finds out he really was her savor and had saved her at that moment when he went back in time. (Full color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might this be ***[Sica Wolf](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=153379)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> On a mission to find the two most important people in her life, Sica steps foot outside the Magician's Tower for the first time ever! She soon meets Karsus, a mercenary swordsman who looks like her first love. Despite being confused for someone else, Karsus offers to help find the people Sica's looking for if she helps him with his work. Thus the two begin their adventure ― one that will change not only the fate of the Empire, but also their hearts! First love or Karsus... who will Sica choose?

When Sica was a small girl, she was hunted by villagers who regarded her as a monster, and saved by a mysterious swordsman who ended up escorting her to the Tower of Magic, where she learned to become a magician.

Years later, she applies to register with a mercenary guild, where she meets a swordsman named Karkus, whom she believes is the same man who saved her years earlier. However, Karkus doesn't recognise her, and points out that he's too young to be the person she's talking about, which she grudgingly accepts. Nonetheless, they become companions and develop feelings for one another.

Much later in the story, they're both thrown years back in time by a teleportation spell that went awry. Karkus ends up saving the younger version of Sica from the villagers and escorting her to the Tower of Magic, and realises that he must've been the person she remembered all along.

[image] [image]

Comment: Ahhhh yes this is it thank you!!!